# React Fullpage and middle header CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, fullpage.js

i'm wondering the way to get the state for each section, using React fullPage.js.

I want to know the way to get section's state, so i can give the css property to the header for each different sections.

Such as, when you get to the website, the header is shown. However, from the second page, the header goes on disapper(display:none).

Thanks for giving me a hand !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple methods:

- Using [fullpage.js `callbacks`](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#callbacks) (See [JS example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/XbPNQv) or [React Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m34yq5q0qx))
- Calling `fullpage_api.getActiveSection` (See [example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/VdpzRN/))
- Using [CSS state classes](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) (See [example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/VwbxbYR) or [example 2](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/wvPgRQm))